# Lint extension in brackets is not being able to find it how to make php from wamp globally accessible

Tags: php, apache, adobe-brackets, php-ini, phplint

I want use a `PHP lint` extension of brackets which needs php running on the system. But I haveve not installed it manually.

I am using `WAMP` which gets installed and configures (Windows, Apache, Mysql, And PHP)automatically.

So now when I run the extension, it is giving me error that `PHP` is not available on your machine.

**Question:** If anyone knows how can I make PHP globally accessible on my computer, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Readme](https://github.com/DoersGuild/brackets-phplint) of the *PHP Lint* extension states that you have to have `php` in your system path.

For Windows edit your PATH Environment Variable and append the folder which contains your `php.exe`. In your case probably `C:\wamp\php`.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks for the help just to add path for me was C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12 and for anyone else looking up this question kindly go to wamp folder and search php.exe and copy the path also this works for this brackets extension as well https://github.com/mikaeljorhult/brackets-php-code-quality-tools